# How can I patch a function stored in a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking, python-mock, python-unittest

How can I make the following test to work?

**mymodule.py**

```
import requests

http_methods = {
    "GET": requests.get,
    "POST": requests.post,
    "PUT": requests.put,
    "DELETE": requests.delete
}

def foo(method):
    r = http_methods[method]("http://some.thing")
    return r.status_code
```

**tests.py**

```
import unittest
from mock import patch
import mymodule

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
    @patch("requests.post")
    def test_foo(self, post):
        post.return_value = 200
        self.assertEquals(mymodule.foo("POST"), 200)
```

When I execute the test I got a `ConnectionError` exception because `foo` is executing the real `requests.post`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? *How can I make the following code to work?* isn't helpful enough for me (at least) to understand.. Please state what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: @Schoolboy the real code is bigger and has a "meaning". I removed all other parts of code that has no direct relation with the problem. My problem is: given a dictionary with several functions, how can I patch them?

Comment: @Schoolboy `patch` decorator from python [mock library](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/).

Answer (score 1):

Try `@patch("mymodule.requests.post")`, see [where to patch](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch)